# Media Player "setOnPreparedListener" not getting called when re-invoking the app after lock/power button pressed

Tags: android

I have done some visibility change in **setOnPreparedListener** but it's not getting called after lock screen and re-invoke. The video is getting played but progress bar I want to close in `setOnPreparedListener` is not closing.

**Same code is working after pressing the home button and re-invoking though.**

This method gets called after unlocking:

```
@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    mVideoProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
    if (stoptime > 0) {
        mVideo.seekTo(stoptime);
    }   
}
```

This is the listener:

```
mVideo.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        Log.d(TAG, "!inside onPrepared");
        mVideoProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

Comment: @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
       mVideoProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
        if (stoptime > 0) {
            mVideo.seekTo(stoptime);
        }
    }